# How to use conversion typeclasses

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, typeclass

Hello i have  trouble understanding what `typeclass` i need to implement for doing mathematical operations with `Int`'s and `Double`'s (for now).

```
data Numeric=I Int | D Double deriving (Show)
```

I want to be able to perform: `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` on `I`'s with `D`'s , compare them and order them .Which typeclass do i need to implement ? `Num`,`Integral`,`Ord` ?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `Rational` (or even a `Double`, though that can lose precision)? Both contain integers as well.

Comment: To find out to which typeclass some method/function belongs, just look up its documentation. This is easiest found [on Hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%2B).

It turns out `+`, `-` and `*` are methods of the [`Num` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num), whereas `/` is a method of [`Fractional`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional).

Comment: You post a lot of questions about this sum type; are you *sure* you don't simply want to add a `Num` constraint to whatever function uses this type instead of being so specific? `fun :: Num a => a -> a` instead of `fun :: Numeric -> Numeric` for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your class instance of `Num` to have `+`, `-`, `*` and most important `fromInteger` and instance of `Fractional` to have `/` and `fromRational`.

Here is small stub for simplified version:

```
data Numeric = N Double
   deriving Show

instance Num Numeric where
   (*) (N a) (N b) = N (a * b) 
   (+) (N a) (N b) = N (a + b) 
   (-) (N a) (N b) = N (a - b) 
   abs (N a) = N $ abs a
   signum (N a) = N $ signum a
   fromInteger a = N $ fromInteger a

instance Fractional Numeric where
   fromRational d = N $ fromRational d
   (/) (N a) (N b) = N (a / b)
```